# In jQuery, how do I add a user input value to a running total based on pre-defined values?

Tags: jquery, input, focus, nan

This is what I have so far, albeit scaled down. I want the user to click on pre-defined values, as in the first two divs, or click on "Input Custom Value" which brings focus to the #enter_custom input where they can enter their own value. The user will add each value option to the total by clicking "Add to Total" after highlighting either predefined value or entering a custom value. Hope that much makes sense.

I cannot for the life of me get the user defined input value to add to the total. Not sure if I need to remove focus before it can be added. I've tried that (and many more failures), but perhaps I was using the wrong approach -- blur() -- or, perhaps I'm on the wrong track altogether. Total displays as NaN for everything I've tried. Help will be much appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $total = 0;
  $('#total').html($total);

  $('.activate').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');

    var $value = $(this).find('input').val();
    var $totalChanger = parseInt($value, 10);

    $('#add').click(function() {
      $('#total').html($total = $total + $totalChanger);
      $('div').removeClass('selected');
      $('#enter_custom').val('');
      $totalChanger = 0;
    }); /* $('#correct').click(function(){ */

    $('#trigger_custom').click(function() {
      if ($total <= 0) {
        alert("You lose!");
      } else {
        $('#enter_custom').focus();
      }
    }); /* $('#trigger_custom').click(function(){ */

  }); /* $('.activate').click(function(){ */

}); /* $(document).ready(function(){ */
```

```css
div {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  border: thin solid #111;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selection:hover,
.selected {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
#custom,
#total {
  cursor: default;
  color: #111;
}
input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.value input {
  display: none;
}
input:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="activate selection value"><input type="text" value="200" disabled/>200</div>

  <div class="activate selection value"><input type="text" value="400" disabled/>400</div>

  <div class="activate selection" id="trigger_custom">Input Custom Value</div>

  <div id="custom"><input id="enter_custom" placeholder="( enter value here )" type="text"></div>

  <div class="selection" id="add">Add to Total</div>

  <div id="total"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `#trigger_custom` does not have a child element `input` , would return `undefined` at `var $value = $(this).find('input').val();` within `$(".activate").click` handler

Comment: I don't want #trigger_custom to have a child element. I want it to prompt a user to enter a custom value in a different location if the current total is greater than zero. There will be multiple "Input Custom Value" options for the same #enter_custom input. I'm guessing this needs to be accomplished outside the $('.activate').click function, but I can't figure it out. Anyone, anyone...?

Comment: Is requirement to add predefined input values to user input value ?